# Contents inside html canvas should be responsive

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have html canvas. Inside of each is a tally boxes, the number of tally boxes is generated according to the number of votes for every candidates. When the vote is 50 below the tally boxes shows completely inside the canvas but when the votes exceeds to 100 above the other tally boxes is missing. They are all display horizontally. What I want now is to display all the tally boxes inside the canvas. I added a css with  max-width: "100%", I thought this would fixed the problem but it can't. What should I need to do about it? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

This is my code below. Special thanks to Shomz.

```js
var tb = angular.module("tb", []);
tb.controller("tallyboxController", function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.label = {
    table: {
      cName: "Candidate's Name",
      cVote: 'Vote',
      cTB: 'Tally Boxes',
      cNV: 'No of votes',
      period: '.'
    },
  };

  $scope.presidents = [{
    no: '1',
    name: 'Jeoanna Lingh',
    votes: 1223,
  },{
    no: '2',
    name: 'Jewel Miller',
    votes: 1234,
  },{
    no: '3',
    name: 'Shin Lee',
    votes: 1001,
  }];

  $scope.candidates = [
    $scope.presidents,
    $scope.vicepresidents
  ];

});


var tb = angular.module('tb');

tb.directive('drawing', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      candidate: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow','black'];

        scope.$watch("candidate.votes", function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log('rendering', newValue);
          render();
        });

        function render() {
          var votes = scope.candidate.votes;
          var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
          var remainder = 0;
          var oneBox = 0;
          
          // clear canvas (needed for subtracting votes)
          // and is a good practice anyway
          element[0].width = element[0].width;

          if (votes > 4) {
            if (remainder = votes % 5) {
              oneBox = (votes - remainder) / 5;
            }
            else {
              oneBox = votes / 5;
            }
          } else {
            remainder = votes;
          }
          
          drawOneBox();          

          function drawOneBox() {
            ;
            for (var i = 0; i < oneBox; i++) {
              
              var color = colors[Math.floor(i/5)];

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }
            
            // recheck the color
            color = colors[Math.floor(oneBox/5)];

            if (remainder == 1) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 2) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 3) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 4) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }
          };
        }
        render();
      } // end 
  };
});
```

```css
canvas {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="tb">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tally Boxes</title>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="tallyboxController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>{{label.table.cName}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cTB}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cNV}}</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in candidates[0]">
          <td>{{value.no}} {{label.table.period}} {{value.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <canvas width="1000" height="30" id="{{value.no}}" candidate="value" drawing></canvas>
          </td>
          <td>{{value.votes}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are setting `canvas` as class when it is a HTML tag.

Comment: Huh what do you mean dippas, Please make it clarify. :-)

Comment: in your CSS you have `.canvas` but `canvas` is an HTML tag , not  a class so you should have `canvas` without dot

Comment: Okay I got it. I deleted the dot and run the code but the other tally boxes are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas can be quite problematic when it comes to responsiveness. Sure, you can use CSS to scale it (remember, CSS dimensions are different than canvas dimensions, and if the are different, the canvas stretches).

So you need to implement a smart responsive technique yourself - think about fetching the available canvas size, and redrawing the boxes accordingly. This could go into window resize callback so it works with window resizing as well.

If you don't want to mess with all that, you can still switch back to using regular images (5 for each color), and using standard HTML/CSS responsiveness practices. If not, you have to recalculate the canvas size on every resize (plus when it first loads) and position the tally boxes accordingly.

Thank you for the mention, btw. :)

---

UPDATE

I see you managed to implement the CSS scaling in the meanwhile, but bear in mind the boxes could get ridiculously small when the number of votes increases; you probably want to use multiple rows.

---

UPDATE 2

This is what I meant - see if this responsive version on canvas works for you. It still needs a little tweaking, but you get the idea:

```js
var tb = angular.module("tb", []);
tb.controller("tallyboxController", function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.label = {
    table: {
      cName: "Candidate's Name",
      cVote: 'Vote',
      cTB: 'Tally Boxes',
      cNV: 'No of votes',
      period: '.'
    },
  };

  $scope.presidents = [{
    no: '1',
    name: 'Jeoanna Lingh',
    votes: 1223,
  }, {
    no: '2',
    name: 'Jewel Miller',
    votes: 1234,
  }, {
    no: '3',
    name: 'Shin Lee',
    votes: 1001,
  }];

  $scope.candidates = [
    $scope.presidents,
    $scope.vicepresidents
  ];

});


var tb = angular.module('tb');

tb.directive('drawing', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      candidate: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'black'];

        scope.$watch("candidate.votes", function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log('rendering', newValue);
          render();
        });

        function render() {
          var votes = scope.candidate.votes;
          var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
          var remainder = 0;
          var oneBox = 0;

          // clear canvas (needed for subtracting votes)
          // and is a good practice anyway
          element[0].width = element[0].width;

          if (votes > 4) {
            if (remainder = votes % 5) {
              oneBox = (votes - remainder) / 5;
            } else {
              oneBox = votes / 5;
            }
          } else {
            remainder = votes;
          }

          window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
          setTimeout(handleResize, 100);

          function handleResize() {
            var c = element[0];
            var width = c.parentNode.offsetWidth;
            var perRow = Math.floor((width - 10) / 25);
            c.width = width;
            c.height = Math.ceil(oneBox / perRow) * 25 + 5;
            console.log(perRow, width, oneBox);
            drawOneBox(perRow);

          }

          function drawOneBox(perRow) {
            for (var r = 0; r < oneBox / perRow; r++) {
              var remainingInRow = (oneBox - r * perRow);
              if (remainingInRow > perRow) remainingInRow = perRow;
              for (var i = 0; i < remainingInRow; i++) {

                var rowOffset = r * 25;

                var color = colors[Math.floor(i / 5)];

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
                ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);

                ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
                ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

                ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
                ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

                ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
                ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

                ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);
                ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);
                ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                ctx.stroke();
              }
            }

            // recheck the color
            color = colors[Math.floor(oneBox / 5)];

            if (remainder == 1) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 2) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 3) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

            if (remainder == 4) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(5 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 5 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

              ctx.moveTo(25 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);
              ctx.lineTo(5 + i * 25, 25 + rowOffset);

              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();
            }

          };
        }
        render();
      } // end 
  };
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="tb">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tally Boxes</title>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="tallyboxController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container-table">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>{{label.table.cName}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cTB}}</td>
          <td>{{label.table.cNV}}</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in candidates[0]">
          <td>{{value.no}} {{label.table.period}} {{value.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <canvas width="1000" height="30" id="{{value.no}}" candidate="value" drawing></canvas>
          </td>
          <td>{{value.votes}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am speechless. :-) . That is what I really need right now. Thank you so much again. :-) I am studying your code right now and familiarizing it. I noticed this variable "var rowOffset = r * 25;" . Why the r is multiply to 25? Can you explain it to me further :-) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. :) 25 seemed to be the height of the boxes (plus the top margin of 5), right? So basically, this pulls down each new row by 25 pixels.